# Power Analysis for Correlation-coefficient

Tags: correlation, statistical-power

From a prior study, a correlation coefficient of 0.9 was achieved with 16 experiments.
Each prior experiment consisted of 10 to 300 subjects.
From going through StackExchange posts I understand sample size and power calculations can be done by using R function (from package `pwr`, on CRAN):

```
pwr.r.test(n=NULL, r=0.9, sig.level=0.05, power = 0.8, alternative = "two.sided")
pwr.r.test(n=16, r=0.9, sig.level=0.05, power = NULL, alternative = "two.sided")
```

How would I estimate power if each of the sixteen observations/experiments consists of 10 subjects?

And if the command below produced an n = 6.
Would this mean then that I will be OK with doing six experiments with 10 subjects each?

```
pwr.r.test(n=NULL, r=0.9, sig.level=0.05, power = 0.8, alternative = "two.sided")

approximate correlation power calculation (arctangh transformation) 

          n = 6.236905
          r = 0.9
  sig.level = 0.05
      power = 0.8
alternative = two.sided
```

Comment: Please clarify: did you run 16 correlations (with 10 to 300 data points each), or just 1 (with 16 data points)?

Comment: One with 16 data points.

Comment: When you use function from R not in base, you should give the package name. I edited in package, please check.

Comment: You should start not only with $r=0.9$ from thye prior study, but ask yourself what is the smallest correlation you care to detect, and then make sure power is high enough for that value.  And ask yourself what is the underlying assumptions behind the function you use (possibly bivariate normalitry?) Are you sure you have binormal data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From each experiment, you get parameter estimates that end up in the correlation to be done later.  The fewer the number of subjects in each experiment, the higher the standard error of that experiment's SE.  That means there will be more noise in the estimate.  The more noise in the estimates, the weaker the apparent correlation, relative to its true value, even if those estimates were unbiased.  How much all this will happen is hard to say without specifying every last detail.  I would simulate your situation to get a sense of what you need.